# Is there a way to specify absolute measurements for an object on the screen that actually work?

Tags: css

I would like to set a `max-width` equal to the real size of a small object that may fit on most of the screens. My test results vary widely between screens, with a difference of about 5mm or more, either on the positive or the negative.

I'm using the W3 example on [EM, PX, PT, CM, IN…](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20restriction%20on%20which%20units%20can%20be%20used%20where.&text=The%20so-called%20absolute%20units,has%20a%20high%20enough%20resolution), which I reproduced here:

```css
.hint::before {
    content: "\270E";
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1.25em;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hint">
    <p>If you have a ruler handy you can check how precise your device
     is: here is a box of 1in (2.54cm) high: <span style="display: block; height: 72pt; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid dashed; line-height: 24pt; font-size: 19pt; text-align: center; margin: 1.2em">↑<br>
     72pt<br>
     ↓</span>
   </p></div>
```

I would like this absolute measurement to work on mobile devices (iOS, Android), using CSS only. I'm about to abandon the endeavour, but want to make sure that am not missing something here (I did read the article mentioned above in full and did tests on three different devices)

Comment: What is the actual purpose behind this? How big something _appears_, still depends a lot on how far the viewer actually is from the screen, so unless you actually want them to measure something by putting a ruler directly onto the glass, I am having a hard time seeing any real point in this.

Comment: In this case it’s an object that fits in your hand and that people carry around all the time. The design choice in this case is to be able limit the size of the object on the screen in case the device screen is large, so it doesn’t look out of proportion with the real one.

It is a subtle design choice